# Do you know any other programming languages that have interactive mode like Python?

Tags: python, language-agnostic, programming-languages, language-features

Python language has a well known feature named [interactive mode](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/interpreter.html#interactive-mode) where the interpreter can read commands directly from tty.
I typically use this mode to test if a given module is in the classpath or to play around and  test some snippets.

Do you know any other programming languages that have Interactive Mode?

If you can, give the name of the languages and where possible, a web reference.
 If it is already mentioned, you can just vote for it.

Comment: This probably should be Community Wiki.

Comment: Probably, but it's fine even if it isn't, tbh.

Comment: Community wiki as requested :).

Comment: Easier to ask for which languages there isn't an implementation that provides an interactive mode.

Comment: @Paul Hankin Too late :) ! I did not know it was such a "common" feature.

Comment: +1 because I learnt the term `repl`.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Most (all?) lisps (including common lisp, scheme and clojure), sml, ocaml, haskell, F#, erlang, scala, ruby, python, lua, groovy, prolog.

Comment: Yep, great list. Except that the ocaml one sucks.

Comment: Quite complete answer. Lacks prolog, though.

Comment: lacks JavaScript, which has interactive interpreters like Rhino or SpiderMonkey, and also the interactive command lines in all current-version browsers.

Comment: @p4bl0: If by "ocaml one sucks" you mean it doesn't allow editing, use `rlwrap ocaml`. Even better, alias it in your shell - I'd never use `ocaml` without it.

@bcherry: if you include interactive interpreters, add Perl too (http://use.perl.org/articles/07/08/30/1729255.shtml)

Answer (score 5):

- PHP can do that too: [PHP from the command line](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.php)
- Does mySQL count? [mySQL Commands](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/mysql-commands.html)
- [JavaScript shell in SpiderMonkey](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Introduction_to_the_JavaScript_shell) (including, but not limited to, Firefox)

Comment: Wrong link for PHP. http://www.phpsh.org/

Comment: Just run `php -a`, but it **sucks** compared to Python's shell.

Comment: `phpsh` is somewhat decent.  Interestingly, it's written in Python.

Answer (score 5):

bash / tcsh / csh / ksh /...

they all are programming languages and have a CLI :)

Answer (score 5):

[Haskell](http://www.haskell.org/) even has two (mainstream) interactive interpreters, [Hugs](http://www.mirrorservice.org/sites/www.haskell.org/hugs/) and [ghci](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/GHC/GHCi).

Answer (score 5):

Tcl/tk has one. It's been there since day one. This is not a feature unique to Python.

Comment: Actually, a Tcl interactive interpreter was first introduced as part of the TclX extension. The `tclsh` program was an innovation introduced in June 1993...

Comment: Thanks for the history lesson. I started using Tcl in '95 which is why I had assumed it had always been there.

Answer (score 5):

As has been pointed out lots of languages can be used interactively, though how conveniently they can be so used varies quite a bit. The interactive environment I'm most familiar with, and one that I have found among the most congenial of all the free environments for interactive programming I've tried (not that I've tried them all) is Slime, a mode for emacs that allows interaction with a running Common Lisp, and can also be used with Clojure, a Lisp for the JVM.

If Lisp isn't your cup of tea a variety of Smalltalk environments are worth mentioning. One of the interesting things about many Smalltalk systems is that they expose almost all of the code that implements the system in the programming environment- if you want you can browse or even rewrite parts of the programming environment as you are using it, just as you would write new code. In fact the line between the system provided to you and the code you are writing is pretty blurry. Squeak is an interesting free Smalltalk, and Cincom offers an evaluation version of their commercial Smalltalk, which is a great environment IMHO.

Anyway, if you're interested in playing with interactive environments you could do worse than to play with those two, though of course there are a lot of other systems out there that allow interactive programming to one degree or another.

Answer (score 3):

Lisp and Scheme have interactive mode.

Comment: Have also used this feature of scheme...

Comment: Lisp was probably the first to invent this interactive way of programming.

Answer (score 3):

C++.

[Seriously](http://www.artificialworlds.net/wiki/IGCC/IGCC).

Comment: And another: http://root.cern.ch/drupal/content/cint

Answer (score 2):

Ruby has `irb`, which is an interactive interpreter, and Ruby is quite similar to Python.

[`irb` at Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interactive_Ruby_Shell)
[Ruby at Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_(programming_language))

Answer (score 2):

[Perl](http://www.perl.org/) - interesting that there are so many answers before this

Answer (score 1):

**Ruby** has it.. also **Groovy** has it (allowing you to test also **Java** code effectively).

Answer (score 1):

I guess one of the first was LISP.
Just try clisp

Answer (score 1):

Most scripting languages will read from stdin and execute code typed at the console if you don't specify a filename to run. Php and perl will all do it.

Ruby has irb.

Lua has a more formal interactive mode like python, which will show you the indent level of your code at the prompt. It's very helpful since lua is typically used as an embedded scripting language, and you don't have to run your full application to test out code snippets.

Answer (score 1):

Lua has an interactive mode as well.

Answer (score 1):

Oh, I've forgotten the BASIC one :)

Answer (score 1):

Prolog has one as well

Answer (score 1):

Even Java has one!

It's called Beanshell: http://www.beanshell.org/

Comment: Beanshell is a scripting language, isn't it?

Comment: Yes and no. You can just start an interactive session with the command bsh. It accepts full fledged Java code with all boilerplate attached but it also parses a simplified version of Java that feels more like a scripting language.

Answer (score 1):

There's one for [C#](http://www.mono-project.com/CsharpRepl).

Comment: @Ken The link you posted goes to this article.  Did you mean to post a link to the interactive C# shell?

Comment: csharp.exe (and gsharp.exe) are included in the distributions of the recent versions of Mono.

Comment: This is why copy-paste coding is bad: I'm not very good at copy and paste.  :P

Answer (score 1):

FORTH comes immediately to mind.

So does APL.

I remember seeing an interactive FORTRAN implementation on an SDS-930 (I think), many, many moons ago.

Answer (score 1):

You can do almost-interactive C# and VB.NET using [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/)

Answer (score 1):

**Logo** programming language.

Some implementations are so interactive that some people don't even use any other mode.

Answer (score 1):

There's a [repl for C](http://neugierig.org/software/c-repl/) too.

Answer (score 1):

R statistic program ;)

Answer (score 1):

Basic on the VIC20 and C64

Answer (score 1):

Any interpreted language is most likely going to have one.

Answer (score 0):

[Erlang](http://www.erlang.org/index.html) does, as well as [Haskell](http://www.haskell.org/) and i'm guessing [Ruby](http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/) does. Also there are Javascript CLIs like [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Scala has [REPL](http://scala-lang.org/node/2097).

> The Scala Interpreter (often called a REPL for Read-Evaluate-Print
>   Loop) sits in an unusual design space - an interactive interpreter for
>   a statically typed language straddles two worlds which historically
>   have been distinct.  In version 2.8 the REPL further exploits the
>   unique possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Basic .NET has an interactive mode.

Answer (score 0):

Windows PowerShell: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_PowerShell

Comment: @systempuntoout: Every non-trivial "just a shell" has its own language, though not necessary useful, extensible or Turing-complete.

Comment: @systempuntoout, @wRAR: And even if it were useful, extensible, and turing-complete, it might be something fairly horrible like `cmd.exe`...

Answer (score 0):

[Boo](http://boo.codehaus.org/) is a nice middle ground between Python and C# - type-inference and procedural-compatible programming, with compatibity with .Net, plus ability to compile to CLR assemblies and .EXE's.

Answer (score 0):

True to its name, the science-oriented and proprietary [Interactive Data Language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IDL_%28programming_language%29) (usually just called IDL, but spelled out here to avoid confusion with the other [IDL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_description_language)) has an interactive mode which many of its users utilize more often than they program in it.